# Making a 0 to nxn matrix and reshape it to pairs

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, reshape

Maybe I am wrong and I don't know how to search for it.

I need to get a list of pairs

(0,0)
(0,1)
(0,2)
...
(0,999)
...
(999,999)

To put these values into a neural network and get the result - just a vector of length (999*999)

Then I can reshape it to (999,999) and have a map of outputs.

So, naive approach is to use

```
for i in range(0, 999):
    for j in range(0, 999):
        list.add(predict(i,j))
```

But it is impossible to use batches

Another naive approach is

```
numbers=[]
for i in range(0, 999):
    for j in range(0, 999):
        numbers.append([i,j])
```

and this works in batches.

Is there any more elegant solution?

Comment: What exactly is required? Single (1-d) list/array of such tuples `(0,1) (0,2) ... (0,999) ... (999,999)` ? If you can post sample output in exact format of requirement, that would help.

Comment: @Parth yes, you are right

Comment: Do you want to include `(0,0), (1,0), (2,0)` and so on? In example you have not given `(0,0)`.

Comment: @Parth yes, they also have to be included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
target_list = np.array([(i,j) for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000)])
```

This `print(target_list)` will give desired list in numpy array format:

```
[[  0   0]
 [  0   1]
 [  0   2]
 ...
 [999 997]
 [999 998]
 [999 999]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry, I cannot increase the post score

Comment: @fisi Welcome. No worries. Glad to help.

Comment: If someone is interested in performance, on my pc this approach works about 10% faster than filling a list in a loop (~800ms vs ~900ms). If we don't create a np.array, it takes about 300ms